# Interpolation of missing matrix values

Tags: matrix, function-construction, interpolation

**Problem statement**

I want to replace missing matrix values, denoted by an integer `0`, with the `Mean` of their surrounding values.

**Example 1**

[image]

Since the missing value and neighbouring zeros don't count, the calculations are as follows:

```
{1 + 2 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3} / 7
```

13/7

```
{2 + 3 + 4 + 9 + 2 + 3 + 4} / 7
```

27/7

**Example 2**

[image]

**Example 3**

[image]

**Corner cases**

[image]

[image]

The latter result seems surprising, bus as I noted above: *The missing value and neighbouring zeros don't count.*

**Question**

How can we do this interpolation in a functional style? Readability is more important than speed.

Comment: Define "surrounding."

Comment: Isn't it defined by the examples and the upvoted answer?

Comment: No.  What is "surrounding" the $(2,1)$ entry in a $3 \times 3$ matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayFilter` might be a good choice:

```
test1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 0, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
ArrayFilter[ZeroToNeighborhoodMean, test1, 1, Padding -> 0]
```

where

```
ZeroToNeighborhoodMean[m : {{_, _, _}, {_, 0, _}, {_, _, _}}] := 
  Total[m, 2]/Count[m, Except[0], {2}];
ZeroToNeighborhoodMean[{{_, _, _}, {_, v_, _}, {_, _, _}}] := v
```

**Update**

To handle the all zeros case, add this:

```
ZeroToNeighborhoodMean[m : {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}] := 0
```

Comment: +1 - This gives all expected results. Except for the `{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}` case. I know, this is a very pedantic remark, almost not worth mentioning.

Comment: Yeah, I honestly don't think your expected result for the all zeros case makes much sense, since you explicitly said that zeros don't matter. You're trying to treat zeros as both placeholders and actual values, and that just won't give you a consistent semantic.

Comment: But it'd be easy enough to add another case for `ZeroToNeighborhoodMean`.

Comment: I agree, it was a mistake to include this degenerate case in the question

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
neighborMean[m_?MatrixQ, {i_, j_}] := Module[{d = Dimensions@m},
   dx = d[[1]];
   dy = d[[2]];
   xr = Range[i - 1, i + 1] // Select[Between[{1, dx}]];
   yr = Range[j - 1, j + 1] // Select[Between[{1, dy}]];
   t = Flatten@DeleteCases[m[[xr, yr]], 0, {2}];
   If[Total@t == 0, 0, Mean@t]
   ];
ipMatrix[m_?MatrixQ] := 
  MapIndexed[If[#1 == 0, neighborMean[m, #2], #] &, m, {2}];

m1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 0, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
m2 = {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 3}};
m3 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 0, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
m4 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
m5 = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}};

testcases = {m1, m2, m3, m4, m5};

ipMatrix /@ testcases // Map[MatrixForm]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Keeping in mind the request for readability over speed (and, I assume, conciseness)

```
surroundingValuesMean[m_] := Module[
  {pos, surroundpos, surroundvals, surroundmean},
  pos = Position[m, 0];
  surroundpos = 
   Flatten[
     Table[{x, y}, {x, Max[1, #[[1]] - 1], Min[Length[m], #[[1]] + 1]}, {y, Max[1, #[[2]] - 1], 
        Min[Length[m[[1]]], #[[2]] + 1]}], 1] & /@ pos;
  surroundvals = Extract[m, #] & /@ surroundpos;
  surroundmean = 
   If[Total[#] == 0, 0, Total[#]/Count[#, Except[0]]] & /@ surroundvals;
  ReplacePart[m, Table[pos[[n]] -> surroundmean[[n]], {n, Length[pos]}]]
  ]

m1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 0, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
m2 = {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 3}};
m3 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 0, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
m4 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
m5 = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}};

MatrixForm /@ surroundingValuesMean /@ {m1, m2, m3, m4, m5}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using CellularAutomaton:

```
ClearAll[boxMatrixMean, matrixInterpolation];
boxMatrixMean[0] = Infinity;
boxMatrixMean[m_?MatrixQ, t_] := 
  If[m[[2, 2]] != 0, m[[2, 2]], 
    Total@# / Max[Count[Unitize@#, 1], 1]& @Flatten@ReplaceAll[m, boxMatrixMean[0] -> 0]];

matrixInterpolation[m_?MatrixQ] :=
 Flatten[
  CellularAutomaton[{boxMatrixMean, {}, {1, 1}}, {m,boxMatrixMean[0]}, {{1}}], 1]

(* Testing *)
m1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 0, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
m2 = {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 3}};
m3 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 0, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
m4 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
m5 = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}};

MatrixForm@*matrixInterpolation /@ {m1, m2, m3, m4, m5}
```

[image]